# Diffrence between a MOF file and WMI provider

Tags: wmi

Can anyone tell me the difference between a Managed Object Format(MOF) file and WMI provider ?

Comment: look this, can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms178709%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Managed Object Format (MOF)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa823192(v=vs.85).aspx) is a language used to define CIM classes and Events. on the other hand the WMI providers are COM objects that implement the CIM  classes (usually using C++), These providers can contain a compiled MOF file. in summary the MOF language is used to describe the classes and evetns and the providers is the implementation of these classes.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. Now I am clear on this. Can you please look into this question that I have posted some days ago its related to WMI "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374588/communication-between-wmi-and-windows-services/27466312#27466312" .                                                                    I have googled a lot and I posted an answer to my own question but still I am a bit unclear at the end. Can you please help me ?